# performance to find specific datarow c#

Tags: performance, linq, c#-4.0

Evening everyone,

I am trying to update a specific column in a datatable I have.
Table is about 500 rows.

I want to find row based on a certain column.  I've been reading the differences between table.select and linq, and from what I read LINQ is supposed to be MUCH fast.

So I tried both and I put in a stopwatch and the results are different.

```
                                    string time1 = "";
                                string time2 = "";
                                string time3 = "";

                                sw.Start();
                                DataRow foundRowA = datatableTodaysMarkets.Select("BBM_Symbol = '" + newBBM + "'").FirstOrDefault();
                                sw.Stop();
                                time1 = sw.Elapsed.ToString();

                                sw.Reset();
                                sw.Start();
                                DataRow foundRow = datatableTodaysMarkets.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Where(r => r[0].ToString() == newBBM).FirstOrDefault();
                                sw.Stop();
                                time2 = sw.Elapsed.ToString();

                                sw.Reset();
                                sw.Start();
                                DataRow results = (from myRow in datatableTodaysMarkets.AsEnumerable()

                                              where myRow.Field<string>("BBM_Symbol") == newBBM

                                              select myRow as DataRow).FirstOrDefault();
                                sw.Stop();
                                time3 = sw.Elapsed.ToString();

                                MessageBox.Show(time1 + "\n" + time2 + "\n" + time3);
```

the results are in the screenshot
[image: speed test]

my first question is I know test 1 is a datatable select statement
and test 3 is linq.
what is test 2 considered.

also, doesn't this show that test 2 is MUCH better than the other options?  Can I take this as gospel or are they many different factors that can change.

thanks!!!

Comment: test2 is in fact the linq search. Whereas test 3 is linq2sql.

Comment: @JanR Well Linq2Sql is still Linq...

Comment: true, but slightly different syntax :) And based on the above test performance :)

Comment: There are a few things fundamentally wrong with this test, the main one being that the tests should be repeated more than once, preferably thousands of times or the results mean nothing.

Comment: Okay. That does help. I didn't know the difference between the three and now I know test2 is straight linq.  Also I can try and run at least a 1000 number of tests.   Thanks for your help!

Comment: Both 2 and 3 are Linq

Comment: Generally speaking. Should one of my choices be the fastest?

Comment: Well if 2 and 3 were improved, they should be pretty much the same. I don't really understand why you are doing some things, like the `Cast<DataRow>` and `AsEnumerable`. They seem redundant.

Comment: I wouldn't get confused by what JanR said though, whether you use the fluent query syntax (test 2) or the query expression syntax (test 3), internally they should be the same thing.

Comment: @JanR Should also say that none of these are Linq-to-SQL, they are both Linq-to-Objects.

Comment: Is there a better way to write number 2?  Don't I need cast data row?

Comment: I just wrote a fourth method. A simple loop from 0 to rows.count. Then break when found. Ran the test 2000 times and this new method seems to be the fastest. Does that make sense?  Feel like this is the least fancy way.